# How to create a hashtable using using values from 2 other hashtables in Powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Lets say I have 2 hashtables :

```
$table1 = @{"A" = "1";
        "B" = "2";
        "C" = "3"}

$table2 = @{"D" = "3";
        "E" = "5";
        "F" = "7"}
```

I want to create a third one using Table1 values as keys

```
$newTable = @{"1" = "3";
          "2" = "5";
          "3" = "7"}`
```

Kind of new to Powershell.
Thx much

Comment: What's the relation? Why does "1" go with "3"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hashtable's order is not preserved by default. For your usecase, you need to make sure the order is being preserved using the `[ordered]` type:

```
$table1 = [ordered]@{
    "A" = "1";
    "B" = "2";
    "C" = "3"
}
$table2 = [ordered]@{
    "D" = "3";
    "E" = "5";
    "F" = "7"
}
```

There is no single method that really does the functionality you want, but what we can do is iterate through the values of both of the hashtables and map them together in a new hashtable

```
$newTable = [ordered]@{}
0..($table1.count - 1) | 
    % { 
        $newTable.add(([Array]$table1.values)[$_], ([Array]$table2.values)[$_]) 
    }
```

Comment: You can use array indexing directly on the ordered dict, eg: `$newTable.Add($table1[$_], $table2[$_])`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen oh wow I didn't realize that the ordered attribute allowed that